# Issues with init script services - Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, boot, init

During boot, I get a series of messages like

```
modem-manager: ... 
modem-manager: ...
.
.
.
```

I tried disabling this feature with

```
sudo update-rc.d -f remove modem-manager remove
```

EDIT:
The output I got is

```
Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/modemmanager ...
```

And I didnt receive any output that seem to disable the links to the actual service.

And further I tried disabling the `lightdm` service at runtime, with:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f lightdm remove
```

Neither of these seem to have any effect when I reboot the system. Am i missing something? thank you, in advance.

Comment: What distribution is this? (Also add a tag for it, if you don't mind.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.10 should be using upstart, not SysV. Try

```
sudo sh -c 'echo manual >> /etc/init/modemmanager.override'
```

or for lightdm

```
sudo sh -C 'echo manual >> /etc/init/lightdm.override'
```

(Note that this last one will keep you from having a graphical login; you probably know that but just in case...)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I simply removed the `*.override` file, to start the service again, this would do? isnt it?

Comment: Yeah, though check and make sure there wasn't already other stuff in the override file (I doubt it, but just in case). If there was other stuff than "manual", just edit the override file and remove the line that says "manual" to get it back.